# Subquery in select not working in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I'm using SQL Server but somehow it won't accept my code (see below error/result). My goal here was to indicate top 10 games in global sales per gaming platform in each column

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    (SELECT g_name FROM vgsales$ WHERE g_platform = 'X360') AS g_namex360, 
    (SELECT g_name FROM vgsales$ WHERE g_platform = 'PS2') AS g_nameps2
FROM 
    vgsales$
ORDER BY 
    Global_Sales;
```

Error Result:

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Below is the table vgsales$

```
CREATE TABLE vgsales$ (
g_rank INT,
g_name VARCHAR(100),
g_platform VARCHAR(100),
g_year INT,
g_genre VARCHAR(100),
g_publisher VARCHAR(100),
Global_Sales INT
);
```

Comment: Do **not**, **never**, **never ever** post images of tables. Post the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements as **text**.

Comment: Thanks for the help and sorry about that. Its my first time here. Any thoughts on how I could resolve this?

Comment: What do you mean by *it won't accept my code* ? Do you get an error? If so then please **show us** that error. Or do you just get no results back? Then please show us the table structure (column names and datatypes and any constraints), and sample data to see what you're selecting from

Comment: Thanks for that. Have now made the question more clear hopefully.

Comment: [Learn to ask smart questions](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subqueries you are using in your select statement should return single value for your query to run without error. The following query will run without any issue, but it won't give you the result you are expecting.

```
SELECT TOP 10
    (SELECT g_name FROM vgsales$ x WHERE g_platform = 'X360' AND a.g_rank = x.g_rank) AS g_namex360, 
    (SELECT g_name FROM vgsales$ p WHERE g_platform = 'PS2' AND a.g_rank = p.g_rank) AS g_nameps2
FROM 
    vgsales$ a
ORDER BY 
    Global_Sales;
```

The following query, although it may not be in the format you want, will return the correct result.

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT
       *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY g_platform ORDER BY Global_Sales DESC) AS RN
    FROM vgsales$ 
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE RN <= 10
```

Comment: This is great! As a newbie to SQL i was frustrated with this and this helped me alot! Thank you so much. Lots to learn as well since there's code i could learn from this.